# get array values in python

Tags: python

I have the values arr1  as 25,26 and arr2 values as A,B

Its always that the number of values in arr1 and arr2 are equal

My question is that

```
          for i in arr1.split(","):
                print i //prints 25 and 26
```

is it not possible to get the values of arr2 in the same loop or should  another loop be written only for this purpose.Basically the idea is that map the values of arr1 and arr2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this with python's `enumerate` function.  This lets you loop through a list and get both its numerical index and its value:

```
array1 = arr1.split(',')
array2 = arr2.split(',')
for i,value in enumerate(array1):
   print value, array2[i]
```

This produces:

```
25 A
26 B
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use zip() function:

```
for zipped in zip(arr1.split(",") , arr2.split(",")):
    someDictionary[zipped[0]] = zipped[1]
```

`zip()` creates `tuple` for each pair of items in collections, then you map one to another. If your 'arrays' have diffrent length, you can use `map()`:

```
a = [1,3,4]
b = [3,4]
print map(None, a, b)
[(1, 3), (3, 4), (4, None)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in (arr1, arr2):
    for j in i.split(","):
        print j
```

Results in output:

```
25
26
A
B
```

And so does:

```
for i in ",".join((arr1, arr2)).split(","):
    print i
```

Although I think this 2nd version is slower, a lot less readable and difficult to work out what's going on. So I'd stick with the first solution, even if it does have an extra loop

Comment: Thanks but i wanted in the marked answer format but +1 for the methods

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it on only one loop, it isn't possible. You would have to do each loop individually. Theres not really a way around it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be as elegant as you hope.  You have to split both, then loop over the size of one array (assuming the other has the same size).